# Running my revel application on windows 10 fail

Tags: windows, revel

I had problem when run my revel app on windows

it create fine but don't run when I try so only get this. any idea?

```
C:\Desarrollo\Web\webpro>revel run -a webpro
Revel executing: run a Revel application
WARN  05:53:33 harness.go:175: No http.addr specified in the app.conf listening on localhost interface only. This will not allow external access to your application
Changed detected, recompiling
Parsing packages, (may require download if not cached)... Completed
ERROR 05:53:38  build.go:406: Build errors                             errors="C:\\Users\\Mario\\go\\pkg\\mod\\github.com\\revel\\revel@v1.0.0\\cache\\memcached.go:11:2: no required module provides package github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache/memcache; to add it:\n\tgo get github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache/memcache\nC:\\Users\\Mario\\go\\pkg\\mod\\github.com\\revel\\revel@v1.0.0\\cache\\redis.go:10:2: no required module provides package github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis; to add it:\n\tgo get github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis\nC:\\Users\\Mario\\go\\pkg\\mod\\github.com\\revel\\revel@v1.0.0\\cache\\inmemory.go:12:2: no required module provides package github.com/patrickmn/go-cache; to add it:\n\tgo get github.com/patrickmn/go-cache\n"
C:\Users\Mario\go\src\webpro\C:\Users\Mario\go\pkg\mod\github.com\revel\revel@v1.0.0\cache\memcached.go:11
WARN  05:53:38  build.go:420: Could not find in GO path                file=C:\\Users\\Mario\\go\\pkg\\mod\\github.com\\revel\\revel@v1.0.0\\cache\\memcached.go:11
ERROR 05:53:38 harness.go:239: Build detected an error                  error="Go Compilation Error (in C:\\Users\\Mario\\go\\pkg\\mod\\github.com\\revel\\revel@v1.0.0\\cache\\memcached.go:11:2): no required module provides package github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache/memcache; to add it:"

Error compiling code, to view error details see proxy running on http://:9000

Time to recompile 5.3684655s
```

I am newer ok

Best

Answer (score 0):

Check your IPv4 address with the ***ipconfig*** command

Open *webpro/conf/app.conf* and paste the IPv4 address into the http.addr parameter